# Comparação de valores

Tags: c#, console

Preciso fazer duas comparações conforme a pessoa vai inserindo dados:

- Maior altura; OK
- Menor altura; (ficou ruim)

Não posso utilizar vetor neste caso, pois é uma exigência do exercício.
No caso até consegui fazer as comparações porém ficou bem 'porco' porque tive que iniciar a variável com um valor absurdo, alguém teria outra forma para resolver?

Usando coisas iniciantes etc.

```
/**
             * 3) Faça um programa que leia dez conjuntos de dois valores: 
             * o primeiro representa o número do aluno e, o segundo, a sua altura em centímetros. 
             * Encontre o aluno mais alto e o mais baixo. Mostre o número do aluno mais alto e o 
             * número do mais baixo, junto com suas alturas.
             * */

            int n_aluno, id=1, n_guarda_maior = 0, n_guarda_menor = 0;
            double altura_cm, maior = 0, menor = 999999999999999;
            string aux;

            while(id <= 4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Número do aluno: ");
                aux = Console.ReadLine();
                n_aluno = Convert.ToInt16(aux);

                Console.WriteLine("Altura em cm: ");
                aux = Console.ReadLine();
                altura_cm = Convert.ToDouble(aux);

                if(altura_cm > maior)
                {
                    maior = altura_cm; //Armazena o maior
                    n_guarda_maior = n_aluno; //Guarda o número do maior
                }

                if(altura_cm < menor)
                {
                    menor = altura_cm; //Armazena o menor
                    n_guarda_menor = n_aluno; //Guarda o número do menor
                } 

                id++; //Proximo aluno
            }

            Console.WriteLine("ID do maior aluno: " + n_guarda_maior + " Altura: " + maior);
            Console.WriteLine("ID do menor aluno: " + n_guarda_menor + " Altura: " + menor);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só verificar se o *loop* está na primeira execução. Se sim, você pode ter certeza que este é o menor até então.

Ou seja, você verifica se o `id` é igual a um (porque `id` é quem controla o *loop*) ou se a altura digitada (`altura_cm`) é menor que a menor altura existente (`menor`).

```
double altura_cm, maior = 0, menor = 0;

/* Resto do código */

if(id == 1 || altura_cm < menor)
{
    menor = altura_cm; //Armazena o menor
    n_guarda_menor = n_aluno; //Guarda o número do menor
}
```

---

Código completo

```
int n_aluno, id = 1, n_guarda_maior = 0, n_guarda_menor = 0;
double altura_cm, maior = 0, menor = 0;
string aux;

while(id <= 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Número do aluno: ");
    aux = Console.ReadLine();
    n_aluno = Convert.ToInt16(aux);

    Console.WriteLine("Altura em cm: ");
    aux = Console.ReadLine();
    altura_cm = Convert.ToDouble(aux);

    if(altura_cm > maior)
    {
        maior = altura_cm; //Armazena o maior
        n_guarda_maior = n_aluno; //Guarda o número do maior
    }

    if(id == 1 || altura_cm < menor)
    {
        menor = altura_cm; //Armazena o menor
        n_guarda_menor = n_aluno; //Guarda o número do menor
    } 

    id++; //Proximo aluno
}

Console.WriteLine("ID do maior aluno: " + n_guarda_maior + " Altura: " + maior);
Console.WriteLine("ID do menor aluno: " + n_guarda_menor + " Altura: " + menor);
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NNdENX)

Comment: Mas ai você não está comparando as alturas dos alunos a ID só serve pra controlar quantos alunos irei cadastrar

Comment: Meu problema está ali: menor = 999999999999 (tá estranho isso)

Comment: @WSS Como assim, jovem? É óbvio que está comparando as alturas ainda. Eu sei que a `id` só serve pra controlar a quantidade. Perceba que é só um comparação (bem lógica por sinal). Se for o primeiro loop, não precisa existir nenhuma comparação de altura porque é impossível existir um valor menor do que o que foi digitado neste momento.

Comment: Ahh entendi o que você fez, colocou a id == 1 porque se não nunca iria dar pra comparar a altura_cm < menor (no caso 0).